# Where can I get codes of material icons?

Tags: icons, material-design

I think there was a change in https://material.io/ - there are no codes for the icons, just 'name version' for example:

```
<i class="material-icons">
   camera_enhance
</i>
```

What's more - they suggest using that for IE9 or below - I remember that previously there were displayed codes instead for IE9 or below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be a bug, there are numerous issues filed:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/766

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/772

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/785

In the mean time, you can refer to this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/flutter/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icons.dart

Comment: I also put up a Codepen, which sometimes has more recently added icons than github-codepoints does.  https://codepen.io/btn-ninja/pen/YrXmax

Answer (score 5):

With the new [version 4.0.0 of icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases/tag/4.0.0), codepoints are accessible in the [font directory](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/font) of the official GitHub repository (the files with `.codepoints` extension contain the codepoints).

The codepoints are also available on the [Google Fonts website](https://fonts.google.com/icons).

You can see the codepoint by clicking on the desired icon:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps

****Step 1**:** Make sure to add the material link index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

****Step 2**:** Go to [https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons)

**Step 3:** Find the icon from the list.

[image: Material Icons]

**step 4:** Click on the icon then you will see a code point on the right panel.
Copy the code point (In the screenshot it is **e8b6**).

**Step 5:** use code point with **`&#x`**

ie. `&#xe8b6;`

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xe8b6;</i>
```

[image]

Comment: This is a repost.

Answer (score 0):

#### Google Fonts

Google recently added codepoints references to every icon directly in their webpage, see here:
https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons:drag_indicator

Every icon has at least the following:

[image]