# How to subset a Google icon font for optimal dowload size?

Tags: css, fonts, google-webfonts

Google contains [instructions](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#optimizing_your_font_requests) for how to subset a font, and even specifies:

> This feature also works for international fonts, allowing you to specify UTF-8 characters. For example, ¡Hola! is represented as: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&text=%c2%a1Hola!`.

Each symbol in the Google Material Icons/Symbols fonts has a codepoint, as specified in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408924/where-can-i-get-codes-of-material-icons).

Is there a way to pass the codepoint values as the value to `&text` URL parameter, so that I can a download a subset of the Material Symbols font with all the icons that I want to use in my app? For example, the search icon has a codepoint of `e8b6`. I tried several incantations, including `&text=e8b6` and `&text=%e8%b6` that didn't download the search icon. Then I found a converter from codepoint to utf-8, which converted `e8b6` to some non-printable characters ^H^F. I then passed `&text=^H^F` and it downloaded the search icon, but it didn't subset the font, i.e. it downloaded the whole font file, rather than a subset of it.